# Map scaling between Stage and RViz

Tags: navigation, simulation, mapping, rviz, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to simulate a custom map in stage using RViz to send goals to the simulated robot.
I recorded the map using a Turtlebot and the map scale is 0.05 according to the .yaml file.
When I open RViz and take a look at the laser scan I see that the distance measured is scaled incorrectly as you can see in the screenshot.
[image description http://t35.imgup.net/Screenshot7842.png](http://t35.imgup.net/Screenshot7842.png)

I also set the map resolution to 0.05 in the stage world file:

```
define block model
(
  size [0.5 0.5 0.5]
  gui_nose 0
)

define topurg ranger
(
    sensor(             
    range [ 0.0  30.0 ]
    fov 270.25
   samples 1081
  )

  # generic model properties
  color "black"
  size [ 0.05 0.05 0.1 ]
)

define erratic position
(
  #size [0.415 0.392 0.25]
  size [0.35 0.35 0.25]
  origin [-0.05 0 0 0]
  gui_nose 1
  drive "diff"
  topurg(pose [ 0.050 0.000 0 0.000 ])
)

define floorplan model
(
  # sombre, sensible, artistic
  color "gray30"

  # most maps will need a bounding box
  boundary 1

  gui_nose 0
  gui_grid 0

  gui_outline 0
  gripper_return 0
  fiducial_return 0
  laser_return 1
)

# set the resolution of the underlying raytrace model in meters
resolution 0.05

interval_sim 100  # simulation timestep in milliseconds


window
( 
  size [ 745.000 448.000 ] 

  #rotate [ 0.000 0.0 ]
  scale 10 
)

# load an environment bitmap
floorplan
( 
  name "cave"
  size [51.2 62.4 0.5]
  pose [-25.7 31.2  0 00.000 ]
  bitmap "bitmaps/dks4e.png"
)

# throw in a robot
erratic( pose [ -20.00000 13.8 0.000000 0 ] name "era" color "blue")
```

This is the .yaml file:

```
image: dks4e.png
resolution: 0.050000
origin: [-34.600000, -13.800000, 0.000000]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
```

The resolution of dks4e.png file is 1024x1248 pixels.
So which value do I need to edit to get the scaling between Stage and RViz right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200526/map-scaling-between-stage-and-rviz/) by [DKS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21308/dks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-01-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-07**:
I don't really see anything wrong with this file you posted, the values of 51.2 and 62.4 look like they should work to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that the pose in .world file should be (-9.0, 17.4) = (-34.6+51.2/2, -13.8+62.4/2). How did you come to your numbers?
Furthermore, do you have a black border around the image file? (otherwise stage trims part of the image).
I recently ran into same problem, so I summarized all that I found about it in  [this post](https://medium.com/@ivangavran/ros-creating-world-file-from-existing-yaml-5b553d31cc53#.88e8vmwuh)

---

Originally posted by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) with karma: 526 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1